# PHP MVC change URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, router

How can I make it so when someone goes to:

`example.com/login`

it will show the

`example.com/application/controller/logincontroller.php` page?

Should I use a PHP router/dispatcher or should I use .htaccess?

Comment: what framework you using?

Comment: @starnzd I am using a custom made framework because i want to learn

Comment: usually you want to write custom router for that, you will be very limited if you use .htaccess for that purpose

Comment: @starnzd Yes, do you have an example I can follow or direct me to a guide?

Comment: you can start with http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/. Basically you need to write a handler for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable

Comment: @starnzd Doesn't that get the controller, model, and params from the url **after** it has been rewritten?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128020/discussion-between-pixie123-and-starnzd).

Comment: It should be done in the php. Especially since only Apache even has a `.htaccess` files. You would not have that option, if your code gets hosted on Nginx or Lighttpd.